# `git show`: different kinds of merge commits

Tags: git

This is a general git question, but I'm using the open source linux kernel source to explain my question better.

If I do:

```
$ git show df57721f9a63e8a1fb9b9b2e70de4aa4c7e0cd2e
```

I see [this output](https://pastebin.com/treMmCWk). Note that this is a merge commit, and that a diff shows up when doing `git show`.

On the other hand, if I do:

```
$ git show 535a265d7f0dd50d8c3a4f8b4f3a452d56bd160f
```

I see [this output](https://pastebin.com/r7JM8WGp). Note that this is also a merge commit, but there is no diff shown when doing `git show`.

I'm trying to understand the following:

1. Why does the former show a diff with `git show`, while the latter does not? Is it due to a merge conflict resolution?
2. Is it possible to cherry-pick the diff shown corresponding to `df57721f9a63e8a1fb9b9b2e70de4aa4c7e0cd2e`? When trying to do the cherry-pick, it asks for a '-m' option corresponding to one of its parents; which is not what I'm trying to do.

Comment: How would you cherry-pick a diff against two different parents?  You don’t have two different versions to which to apply it.

Comment: This does not answer my question unfortunately, especially the first one. I don't understand why some merge commits have a corresponding diff(which shows up with git show), while some others do not.

Comment: The top answer there explicitly mentions when `git show` does and does not show a diff for a merge commit.

Answer (score 0):

In Git, when you perform a `git show` on a merge commit, the displayed differences depend on the commit history and the changes introduced during the merge. The differences you see or don't see are related to the way the merge was conducted and the resulting changes.

Here's why you might be seeing different behaviors for the two merge commits:

**Showing Differences in Merge Commits:**

When `git show` displays differences for a merge commit, it usually    means that the merge itself introduced changes, i.e., there were    conflicting changes between the branches being merged. Git can show    the differences resulting from conflict resolution or changes made    during the merge process.

**No Differences Shown in Merge Commits:**

If `git show` does not display differences for a merge commit, it suggests that the merge did not introduce any additional changes. This scenario might occur if the merge was a "fast-forward" merge, where Git simply moved the branch pointer without creating an additional merge commit because no conflicting changes existed between the branches.

**Regarding cherry-picking a specific diff from a merge commit:**

Cherry-picking a specific diff from a merge commit is not straightforward because merge commits represent the integration of changes from multiple branches. Git requires you to specify which parent's changes you want to pick when cherry-picking a merge commit.
When attempting to cherry-pick a merge commit, Git needs to know which parent's changes to apply:

```
git cherry-pick -m 1 df57721f9a63e8a1fb9b9b2e70de4aa4c7e0cd2e
```

Here, -m 1 specifies the first parent. You might need to determine the appropriate parent number based on the branches' merge history.

If you're interested in cherry-picking changes introduced by a specific branch into your current branch, consider using the branch name or commit hash from that branch directly instead of the merge commit.

Remember, cherry-picking from a merge commit involves choosing one side of the merge, and understanding the context of changes introduced by different branches is crucial to cherry-picking effectively.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to talk about the changes shown for the merge commit of a fast-forward merge, because as you rightly say, a fast-forward is when _no merge commit is created_. The case of "no differences shown" is where a merge commit _was_ created (otherwise, you couldn't name it as an argument to `git show`), but there were no changes _other than those from the two ancestors_. In other words, when there was no conflict resolution or other changes added during the merge process.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the diff headers:

```
diff --cc arch/arm64/mm/trans_pgd.c
```

`diff --cc`. From `man git show`:[1]

> For commits it shows the log message and textual diff. It also presents
> the merge commit in a special format as produced by `git diff-tree --cc`

And then from `man git diff-tree`:

> This flag changes the way a merge commit patch is displayed, in a
> similar way to the -c option. It implies the -c and -p options and
> further compresses the patch output by omitting uninteresting hunks
> whose contents in the parents have only two variants and the merge
> result picks one of them without modification. When all hunks are
> uninteresting, the commit itself and the commit log message are not
> shown, just like in any other "empty diff" case.

This (tree) diff variant doesn’t show you any diff content for things that
could be automatically merged. It only shows hunks if both parents had
modifications there. See the first hunk from your example:

```
diff --cc arch/arm64/mm/trans_pgd.c
index e9ad391fc8ea,a01493f3a06f..7b14df3c6477
--- a/arch/arm64/mm/trans_pgd.c
+++ b/arch/arm64/mm/trans_pgd.c
@@@ -41,9 -40,8 +41,9 @@@ static void _copy_pte(pte_t *dst_ptep,
         * read only (code, rodata). Clear the RDONLY bit from
         * the temporary mappings we use during restore.
         */
-       set_pte(dst_ptep, pte_mkwrite(pte));
+       set_pte(dst_ptep, pte_mkwrite_novma(pte));
 -  } else if (debug_pagealloc_enabled() && !pte_none(pte)) {
 +  } else if ((debug_pagealloc_enabled() ||
 +         is_kfence_address((void *)addr)) && !pte_none(pte)) {
        /*
         * debug_pagealloc will removed the PTE_VALID bit if
         * the page isn't in use by the resume kernel. It may have
```

Notice that there are two diffs here (see one-character indentation). That
means that the hunks overlapped and there was a conflict. You can recreate
the conflict with:

```
$ git show --remerge-diff df57721f9a63e8a1fb9b9b2e70de4aa4c7e0cd2e
[...]
diff --git a/arch/arm64/mm/trans_pgd.c b/arch/arm64/mm/trans_pgd.c
remerge CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in arch/arm64/mm/trans_pgd.c
index 297b0f83b2596..7b14df3c64776 100644
--- a/arch/arm64/mm/trans_pgd.c
+++ b/arch/arm64/mm/trans_pgd.c
@@ -41,17 +41,9 @@ static void _copy_pte(pte_t *dst_ptep, pte_t *src_ptep, unsigned long addr)
                 * read only (code, rodata). Clear the RDONLY bit from
                 * the temporary mappings we use during restore.
                 */
-<<<<<<< b97d64c722598 (Merge tag '6.6-rc-smb3-client-fixes-part1' of git://git.samba.org/sfrench/cifs-2.6)
-               set_pte(dst_ptep, pte_mkwrite(pte));
+               set_pte(dst_ptep, pte_mkwrite_novma(pte));
        } else if ((debug_pagealloc_enabled() ||
                   is_kfence_address((void *)addr)) && !pte_none(pte)) {
-||||||| 06c2afb862f9d
-               set_pte(dst_ptep, pte_mkwrite(pte));
-       } else if (debug_pagealloc_enabled() && !pte_none(pte)) {
-=======
-               set_pte(dst_ptep, pte_mkwrite_novma(pte));
-       } else if (debug_pagealloc_enabled() && !pte_none(pte)) {
->>>>>>> 1fe428d3692fb (x86/shstk: Change order of __user in type)
```

> Is it possible to cherry-pick the diff shown corresponding to
> df57721f9a63e8a1fb9b9b2e70de4aa4c7e0cd2e?

Yes. If you pick the parent. A cherry-pick is an application of a regular
diff, i.e. the state of one single commit compared to another single
commit. But the diff above shows how the code changed relative to both of
the parents. You need to (like you said) pick one of the parents with
`-m`.

git(1) doesn’t privilege any parent in a merge, even though we might often
privilege the first parent (in this case: Linus Torvalds’ mainline
(`master`)). So you have to explicitly say which one.

#### Notes

1. On git version 2.43.0.rc1 (I guess I should upgrade soon)